# How to enable Draconian Error Handling for HTML parsers?

Tags: html

How can I enable the [*Draconian Error Handling*](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/DraconianErrorHandling) on an HTML page in a web browser like Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox if I don't own the page where I want to enable it?

Answer (score 2):

The term *Draconian Error Handling*, as applied to web pages, usually refers to throwing XML parse errors to the user instead of using the HTML parsing algorithm.

The easiest way to trigger this (assuming you use a browser which doesn't automatically fallback to the HTML parsing algorithm when an XML error is hit) is to access the page through a proxy that replaces the `Content-Type` HTTP header with one claiming it is `application/xhtml+xml`.

… but you'd probably get more useful results by using markup validation software instead.

Comment: I'm looking to enable the *Draconian Error Handling* using the rules of HTML, not of XML/XHTML, using the `application/xhtml+xml` as `Content-Type` the page would be parsed as XHTML/XML, or am I wrong?

Comment: The rules of HTML don't include any kind of Draconian Error Handling.

Comment: Draconian Error Handling just means that at the first error of the page the parsing is stopped, so it's applicable to HTML as well.

Comment: Use a validator. If you want to do it every time you load a page, then set up a proxy that validates each page before passing it along to the browser. [This Perl module](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst::TraitFor::View::MarkupValidation) does it for content going out of Catalyst (an MVC framework), you could do something similar for content going through a proxy.

Comment: So there isn't a way to configure browsers to use the Draconian?

Comment: No, there isn't. The rules of HTML describe how to handle errors. If a browser were to give up and stop, it would be in violation of the spec.

Comment: browsers handle errors in different ways, Google Chrome fix tons of bugs and typos, Firefox is more strict, etc... A "strict mode" for HTML would not be so far from what they already do with their custom error handlings.

Comment: @Quentin See [parse error](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parse-error): "The error handling for parse errors is well-defined (that's the processing rules described throughout this specification), but user agents, while parsing an HTML document, **may [abort the parser](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#abort-a-parser) at the first parse error** that they encounter for which they do not wish to apply the rules described in this specification."

Comment: @Oriol — Hmm. Never noticed that before. Well, they may, but no browser does, so it isn't particularly relevant.